# What is the reason to add quotation marks around R function names?

Tags: r, function, syntax

What is the difference between defining a function called myfunction as

```
"myfunction" <- function(<arguments>){<body>}
```

and

```
myfunction <- function(<arguments>){<body>}
```

furthermore: what about the comments which are usually placed around such a function, i.e.

```
#myfunction{{{

 "myfunction" <- function(<arguments>){<body>}

#}}}
```

are they just for documentation or are they really necessary (if so for what)?

EDIT: I have been asked for an example where comments like

```
#myfunction{{{
```

are used: For example here https://github.com/cran/quantmod/blob/master/R/getSymbols.R

Comment: Along the lines of @BrodieG's answer, a common example of this is [infix functions](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#special-calls), e.g. `"%>%" <- function(x,y) {...}`.

Comment: Where are you finding functions defined with the `#myfun {{{` business?

Comment: Added an example for the #myfun {{{ comment

Comment: The `#{{{` and `#}}}` comments are for [vim folding](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Folding).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The quoted version allows otherwise illegal function names:

```
> "my function" <- function() NULL
> "my function"()
NULL
```

Note that most people use backticks to make it clear they are referring to a name rather than a character string.  This allows you to do some really odd things as alluded to in `?assign`:

```
> a <- 1:3
> "a[1]" <- 55
> a[1]
[1] 1
> "a[1]"
[1] "a[1]"
> `a[1]`
[1] 55
```

Comment: You can also use backticks for this: \`my function\` <- function() NULL

Comment: See [R: Quotes](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Quotes.html).

Comment: thx for the reply. I added an additional part to the question, i.e. about the comments (that's why I have not yet accepted your answer)

Comment: Re the comments, those don't do anything as far as I can tell.  They might be part of some documentation framework.  `roxygen` uses comments of the form `#' @param ...`, but I haven't seen that form of comment before.

Comment: Me neither. Can you provide an example where you saw that form of comments? @chuchikaeschtli

Comment: Regarding the comments --> added example to the original question